# Adding Json Object into url

Tags: html, json, sql-server, servlets

I want to be able to delete item based on the book_id.

```
tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr><td>' + obj.book_id + '</td><td>' + <a href="delete_books?book_id=" + obj.book_id + >Delete</a> + '</td></tr>'
```

I am not sure how to form the url. The link can't seem to work.
I want to be able to retrieve the id and delete in my  servlet file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr><td>' + obj.book_id + '</td><td>' + '<a href=' + 'delete_books?book_id=' + obj.book_id + '>Delete</a></td></tr>');
```

Comment: It is an answer, however it is not a good practice according to Notty Boi.

Answer (score 2):

As Dane has mentioned, it is not advisable to expose parameters in the url. Using an AJAX POST/DELETE call would be a better option. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

good question, however, it is not advisable to base your delete request on a URL query which can be easily manipulated by others. Sending the json object through an AJAX call is a better practice.
- Notty Boi